# TFS 2015: update Associated Items on successful build

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a TFS Build 2015 definition (not XAML). And I have a set of work items (bugs, for example). They linked to changesets which are associated to the build. When my build is finished successfully I can see these items on the build Summary page in the "Associated work items" section.

The question is: I want to change status of all these items automatically to something like "Ready for QA".

How can I achieve this?

I don't need a detailed explanation, just some quick directions, where to look, how to grab a TFS build related information in a script or something like this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you need to change the work item to a customize state such as "Ready for QA".

To achieve this you need to use a powershell script in the build pipeline, obtain the base addresses of your team collection and get the work items related to the build, then use the **Rest API** to  [Update work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items),such as `system.state` field.

For detail steps please refer below two blogs, even it's updating *Integration Build* value, the same mechanism:

- [UPDATE WORK ITEMS WITH BUILD NUMBER DURING VNEXT BUILDS](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2016/10/update-work-items-with-build-number-during-vnext-builds/)
- [Build association with work Items in vNext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/09/build-association-with-work-items-in-vnext/)

Comment: Also, just in case anybody wonders and doesn't want to look through links. That's how you get work items associated to concrete build: `https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version={version}`